# Searching in javascript (D3)

Tags: javascript, csv, search, d3.js

I want to create a simple search box wherein I am searching using a particular column in the dataset

Using D3 and a CSV dataset, I am able to read the rows, but how do I go about searching on a specific column (eg: ID here)

Code :

```
d3.csv("search.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    ID: d.ID, 
    history: d.History,
    objective: d.Objective,
    learning : d.Learning 
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
});
```

I need to understand how to create a search function, wherein, we can search and the auto-suggestions come up. I have looked at various examples, but don't know how to go about this inside the D3 CSV filter.

Examples looked at 
( http://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950       ;
http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ztaz6/2/ )
 )

Any directions/approach will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A simple [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should be a sufficient "search" method for this:

```
  var filterText = "some text to search";

  var filteredData = data.filter(function(d){
    return (d.ID.indexOf(filterText) === 0); // does it start with the string?
  });
```

Here's a little working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="filterOn" />
    <div id="filteredList"></div>
    <script>
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      data.push({
        ID: (Math.random() * 10 + '').replace(".","")
      });
    }
    
    onFilter();
    
    d3.select('#filterOn').on('keyup', onFilter);
    
    function onFilter(){

      var filterText = d3.select('#filterOn').property('value');
      
      filteredData = data;
      if (filterText !== ""){
        var filteredData = data.filter(function(d){
          return (d.ID.indexOf(filterText) === 0);
        });
      }
      
      d3.select('#filteredList').html(
        filteredData.map(function(d){
          return d.ID;
        }).join("<br/>")
      );
    }

    
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```